# Jsonpath for nested JSON objects

Tags: json, jsonpath

I have a JSON with nested fields:

```
  [
    {
    "Platform Parent Dato Id": "23768",
    "Platform Dato Id": "24138",
    "Platform Dato Name": "Random Europe",
    "Platform mission Id": "111112",
    "Platform submission Id": "638687",
    "Platform submission Flight Id": "863524",
    "Start Date": "2017-12-01",
    "End Date": "2017-12-02",
    "Platform Compensation": 109.0909,
    "Total Value": 909.0909,
    "Goal": "200000.0000",
    "Value Information": {
      "Platform Compensation": [
        {
          "Platform mission Id": "111112",
          "Platform submission Id": "638687",
          "Platform submission Flight Id": "863524",
          "Value Rate": "14.0000",
          "Value": 109.0909
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "Platform Parent Dato Id": "23768",
    "Platform Dato Id": "24138",
    "Platform Dato Name": "Random Europe",
    "Platform mission Id": "111113",
    "Platform submission Id": "638687",
    "Platform submission Flight Id": "863524",
    "Start Date": "2017-12-01",
    "End Date": "2017-12-02",
    "Platform Compensation": 109.0909,
    "Total Value": 909.0909,
    "Goal": "200000.0000",
    "Value Information": {
      "Platform Compensation": [
        {
          "Platform mission Id": "111113",
          "Platform submission Id": "638687",
          "Platform submission Flight Id": "863524",
          "Value Rate": "12.0000",
          "Value": 109.0909
        }
      ]
    }
  }
  ]
```

and I am using a JSONPATH in order to get the `Value Rate` from the `Value Information` nest.

I have pasted my JSON text in this website: http://jsonpath.com/
and after using this line:

```
$[*].['Platform Compensation'].['Value Rate']
```

I am getting this:

[image]

and after using this line:

```
$.['Value Information'].['Platform Compensation'].['Platform mission Id']
```

I am getting this:

[image]

What I am trying to return (output) is the following:

[image]

but I cannot find the right syntax to combine those two in one line and return both with one JSONPATH query.

Comment: $.['Value Information'].['Platform Compensation'].* ,   [this](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) may help you

Comment: @Onkar That returns all the fields of the nested object. Which is fine. But how can I also get (for example) the "Platform Parent Dato Id"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`jsonpath` can be used to select **values** for given expressions and - in some implementations - for customised predicates but it does not support projections.

You can use `jsonpath` to filter your given JSON. For example:

- Return an array containing all of the `Platform Compensation` values:

  ```
  $.['Value Information'].['Platform Compensation'].['Platform mission Id']
  ```
- Return an array containing all of the `Platform mission Id` values:

  ```
  $.['Value Information'].['Platform Compensation']
  ```

But you cannot use `jsonpath` to a read a sub-set of **keys and values**. To read a sub-set of keys and values you would need to use JSON de/serialisation library. Commonly used libraries - in the Java world - are such as [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Here's an example using Jackson:

```
String json = "...";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> asMap = mapper.readValue(json, Map.class);

Map<String, Object> transformed = new HashMap<>();
transformed.put("Platform mission Id", asMap.get("Platform mission Id"));
transformed.put("Value Rate", asMap.get("Value Rate"));

String result = mapper.writeValueAsString(transformed);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Jayway](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) implementation let you do that.
The jsonpath would be

`$.[*]['Value Information']['Platform Compensation'][*]['Platform mission Id', 'Value Rate']`

You can try it in this website http://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/